# Overhead of using Yii::app()->db multiple times?

Tags: yii

if I have to do multiple queries in a row, is it better to do this:

```
$connection = Yii::app()->db;
```

once... and then keep using $connection, or is there an overhead if I have multiple functions like this:

```
function mainFunction() {
  $dbResult1 = dbresult1();
  $dbResult2 = dbresult2();    
  $dbResult2 = dbresult3();
}

function dbresult1() {
   $connection = Yii::app()->db;
   // do stuff
   return $result;
}

function dbresult2() {
   $connection = Yii::app()->db;
   // do stuff
   return $result;
}

function dbresult3() {
   $connection = Yii::app()->db;
   // do stuff
   return $result;
}
```

Would it be better to do this:

```
function mainFunction() {
  $connection = Yii::app()->db;
  // do stuff with $connection for $dbResult1
  // do stuff with $connection for $dbResult2
  // do stuff with $connection for $dbResult3
}
```

?

Comment: if the functions are inside class that extends CActiveRecord, use `$this->getDbConnection()` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can trace the source code to see what happens when you call `Yii::app()->db`:

`Yii::app()` returns the static `app` property of `YiiBase`. You can see the source code [here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.13/framework/YiiBase.php#L132).

```
public static function app()
{
    return self::$_app;
}
```

`Yii::app()->db` here it gets more interesting, because something gets looked up. You can see the source code [here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.13/framework/base/CApplication.php#L436).

```
public function getDb()
{
    return $this->getComponent('db');
}
```

`getComponent()` is a method of `CModule` you find the source code [here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.13/framework/base/CModule.php#L375).

```
public function getComponent($id,$createIfNull=true)
{
    if(isset($this->_components[$id]))
        return $this->_components[$id];
    elseif(isset($this->_componentConfig[$id]) && $createIfNull)
    {
        $config=$this->_componentConfig[$id];
        if(!isset($config['enabled']) || $config['enabled'])
        {
            Yii::trace("Loading \"$id\" application component",'system.CModule');
            unset($config['enabled']);
            $component=Yii::createComponent($config);
            $component->init();
            return $this->_components[$id]=$component;
        }
    }
}
```

As you see `Yii::app()->db` results in a few method calls and an array lookup. If performance is highly critical you might should cache the db instance. Else I would target on writing clean and readable code and won't care about such little tweaks.

Comment: The app's db component in particular is also a core component, therefore it is already initialized, as part of app initialization with [`regiserCoreComponents`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CApplication#registerCoreComponents-detail).